# Ласка и зверек

Tags: этимология

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли что-то общее между лаской, в смысле, нежностью, и лаской - зверьком из семейства куньих? Откуда совпадение?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ВАРИАНТЫ ПРОИСХОЖДЕНИЯ НАЗВАНИЯ

Слово "ласка" происходит от слова "лазка" и восходит к глаголу "лазить". Ласка действительно проворно лазает меж камней, корней деревьев, кустов.

Фасмер пишет, что в вопросе нет ясности, приводит несколько версий, наиболее вероятной считает все же версию связи со словом "ласкать". Связь же между хищным зверьком и ласковостью объясняет тем, что слово "ласка" было первоначально заменителем какого-то табуированного слова.

Скорее всего, слово ласка тождественно названию птицы ласточка (и его многочисленным вариантам: ластка, ластовка, ластушка, ластица, ластовица), вместе с которым оно восходит к славянскому laska "любовь, ласка", которое употреблено как название зверька по мотивам табу.

Родственное с ласый - "ласковый, льстивый, жадный, падкий на лакомства". Далее сюда же лат. lasc–vus - "резвый, шаловливый; разнузданный, сладострастный".

ПРО ЛАСКУ http://selenaart.ru/post190431476

Это маленькое и такое симпатичное животное в  мифах и легендах разных народов мира, такое же популярное, как  лиса в русских сказках. По древним поверьям под видом этого зверька часто появляется женщина (фея, волшебница, колдунья или соблазнительница, невеста или молодая замужняя женщина в зависимости от обстоятельств).Само это слово буквально передает природу женских чар, используемых для того, что­бы отвлечь внимание и добиться же­лаемого результата.В европейских сказках коварная женщина выступает в образе пушистой ласки, пытающейся соблазнить или сбить со следа охотника.

http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/linnen/post117336396
 Поверья гласят, что когда-то во времена стародавние ласка была нежной девушкой. Однажды ее бросил жених, и ласка от тоски превратилась в зверька. С тех пор она вредит девушкам и женщинам, мешает им встречаться с мужчинами. Чтобы задобрить ласку, нужно проделать такой обряд. Налить в чарку меда, в другую чарку вина и поставить рядом фигурку ласки, слепленную из теста, и фигурку мужа ласки.Читать заклинание: «Государыня ласка! Я сделаю тебя золотой и серебряной, дам тебе мужа, чтобы ты повенчалась, имела свой дом и стала хозяйкой. Добро пожаловать, государыня ласка!»

Answer (score 0):

Интересно, а где Фасмеровская версия?

Этимология

Происходит от формы, родств. ла́сица, ла́стка, укр. ла́сиця, ла́стка, болг. ла́сица, сербохорв. ла̏сица, ла̏са — то же, ла̏саст «цвета ласки», словенск. lásica, чешск. lаsiсе, словацк. lаsiса, польск. ɫаsiса, ɫаskа, н.-луж. ɫаsуса. Родственно латышск. luõss «блеклый, белесоватый, желто-серый». Этимолог Бернекер считает возможным родство с ла́сый «жадный, лакомый, падкий на лакомства». Другие допускают связь с ла́ститься. Ср.-нж.-нем. lasteken «ласка», laskifell заимств. из русск. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

Трубачев указывает также на исследователей, которые на основании др.-чешск. vlasicě и болг. власица восстанавливают праслав. vьlаsъkа, якобы родственное герм. wisulō(n) — то же. Другие сближают слав. слово с нов.-перс. rāsū «ласка». Скорее всего, по мнению Трубачева, название зверя ласка тождественно названию птицы ласточка (и его многочисленным вариантам), вместе с которым оно восходит к слав. laska «любовь, ласка», которое употреблено для обозначения зверька по мотивам табу.